# RegionManager can't navigate twice

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm using Prism on WPF and i have an issue with navigation.
When I click Add Item, it navigating just fine.
when I'm going back to the previous page and clicking Add Item again
it's doesn't go to the page that it spouse to.

At the first time it going to the page.
Going back to the main page.
the clicking add item.
nothing happens

_regionManager.RequestNavigate(Regions.ItemManage, new Uri(Pages.AddItemView, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

No error messages

Comment: What's the result provided by `RequestNavigate` through the `navigationCallback`?

Comment: I solved the issue, By Adding:            _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(Regions.MainRegion, typeof(MainView));

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Where did you add that line exactly? I added it in the constructor but made no difference unfortunately :(